# Rails migration runs without errors but doesnt create tsvector column, GIN index or TRIGGER

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pg-search

I'm currently implementing search functionality in my rails app using pg_search for PostgreSQL full text search. Unfortunately, I'm having a problem with getting the migration to add the tsvector column, GIN INDEX and the TRIGGER in the listings table. The migration runs successfully but doesn't create the things specified in the migration file.

Error when trying to access the tsv column:

```
I, [2020-03-22T10:49:43.273416 #64203]  INFO -- : Started GET "/api/v1/public/search?q=Adidas" for ::1 at 2020-03-22 10:49:43 +1000
D, [2020-03-22T10:49:43.367465 #64203] DEBUG -- :    (6.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
I, [2020-03-22T10:49:43.383171 #64203]  INFO -- : Processing by Api::V1::Public::ListingsController#search as */*
I, [2020-03-22T10:49:43.383234 #64203]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"q"=>"Adidas"}
D, [2020-03-22T10:49:43.638039 #64203] DEBUG -- :   Listing Load (12.4ms)  SELECT "listings".* FROM "listings" INNER JOIN (SELECT "listings"."id" AS pg_search_id, (ts_rank(("listings"."tsv"), (to_tsquery('simple', ''' ' || 'Adidas' || ' ''' || ':*')), 0)) AS rank FROM "listings" WHERE (("listings"."tsv") @@ (to_tsquery('simple', ''' ' || 'Adidas' || ' ''' || ':*')))) AS pg_search_8a836f245cd6a84ba9cbd1 ON "listings"."id" = pg_search_8a836f245cd6a84ba9cbd1.pg_search_id ORDER BY pg_search_8a836f245cd6a84ba9cbd1.rank DESC, "listings"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 100]]
D, [2020-03-22T10:49:43.638832 #64203] DEBUG -- :   ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:47:in `public_render_listings_helper'
I, [2020-03-22T10:49:43.639121 #64203]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 256ms (ActiveRecord: 22.8ms | Allocations: 45123)


F, [2020-03-22T10:49:43.640013 #64203] FATAL -- :
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column listings.tsv does not exist
LINE 1: ...SELECT "listings"."id" AS pg_search_id, (ts_rank(("listings"...
                                                             ^
):
```

The Migration file:

```
class AddTsVectorColumns < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    def up
      add_column :listings, :tsv, :tsvector
      add_index :listings, :tsv, using: 'gin'

      execute <<-SQL
        CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_listings_tsv() RETURNS trigger AS $$
        BEGIN
          new.tsv := (
            SELECT
              setweight(to_tsvector(l.item_name), 'A') ||
              setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce((string_agg(brands.name, ' ')), '')), 'A') ||
              setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce((string_agg(colours.name, ' ')), '')), 'B') ||
              setweight(to_tsvector(l.description), 'B') ||
              setweight(to_tsvector(categories.name), 'B') ||
              setweight(to_tsvector(sub_categories.name), 'B') ||
              setweight(to_tsvector(sizes.name), 'B') ||
              setweight(to_tsvector(users.username), 'C')


            FROM listings l
            JOIN users ON users.id = l.user_id
            JOIN categories ON categories.id = l.category_id
            JOIN sub_categories ON sub_categories.id = l.sub_category_id
            JOIN sizes ON sizes.id = l.size_id
            JOIN conditions ON conditions.id = l.condition_id

            -- Associative Tables
            JOIN brands_listings ON brands_listings.listing_id = brands_listings.brand_id
            JOIN brands ON brands.id = brands_listings.brand_id
            JOIN colours_listings ON colours_listings.listing_id = colours_listings.colour_id
            JOIN colours ON colours.id = colours_listings.colour_id
            WHERE l.id = new.id
            GROUP BY l.id, users.id, categories.id, sub_categories.id, sizes.id, conditions.id
          );
          RETURN new;
        END;
        $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

        CREATE TRIGGER tsvectorupdate BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
        ON listings FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_listings_tsv();
      SQL
    end

    def down
      execute <<-SQL
        DROP TRIGGER tsvectorupdate
        ON listings
      SQL

      remove_index :listings, :tsv
      remove_column :listings, :tsv
    end
  end
end
```

The output of the migration:

```
D, [2020-03-22T13:23:39.965602 #70710] DEBUG -- :   primary::SchemaMigration Create (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" ("version") VALUES ($1) RETURNING "version"  [["version", "20200313140854"]]
D, [2020-03-22T13:23:39.968646 #70710] DEBUG -- :    (0.9ms)  COMMIT
I, [2020-03-22T13:23:39.969992 #70710]  INFO -- : Migrating to AddTsVectorColumns (20200321060306)
== 20200321060306 AddTsVectorColumns: migrating ===============================
== 20200321060306 AddTsVectorColumns: migrated (0.0000s) ======================

D, [2020-03-22T13:23:39.973220 #70710] DEBUG -- :    (0.4ms)  BEGIN
D, [2020-03-22T13:23:39.975042 #70710] DEBUG -- :   primary::SchemaMigration Create (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" ("version") VALUES ($1) RETURNING "version"  [["version", "20200321060306"]]
D, [2020-03-22T13:23:39.977113 #70710] DEBUG -- :    (0.4ms)  COMMIT
D, [2020-03-22T13:23:39.986874 #70710] DEBUG -- :   ActiveRecord::InternalMetadata Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "ar_internal_metadata".* FROM "ar_internal_metadata" WHERE "ar_internal_metadata"."key" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["key", "environment"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2020-03-22T13:23:39.993805 #70710] DEBUG -- :    (0.2ms)  BEGIN
D, [2020-03-22T13:23:39.999419 #70710] DEBUG -- :   ActiveRecord::InternalMetadata Create (4.2ms)  INSERT INTO "ar_internal_metadata" ("key", "value", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "key"  [["key", "environment"], ["value", "development"], ["created_at", "2020-03-22 03:23:39.992922"], ["updated_at", "2020-03-22 03:23:39.992922"]]
D, [2020-03-22T13:23:40.002363 #70710] DEBUG -- :    (0.7ms)  COMMIT
D, [2020-03-22T13:23:40.003788 #70710] DEBUG -- :    (0.4ms)  SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(6123583507257778380)
D, [2020-03-22T13:23:40.258046 #70710] DEBUG -- :    (0.6ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
```

The listing model (where the tsv column is used):

```
class Listing < ApplicationRecord
  include PgSearch::Model

  pg_search_scope(
    :search,
    against: [],
    using: {
      tsearch: {
        tsvector_column: 'tsv',
        any_word: true,
        prefix: true,
        negation: true,
        dictionary: 'simple'
      }
    }
  )
end
```

Extract from the sql schema (with config.active_record.schema_format = :sql) -- -- PostgreSQL database dump --

```
SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;

--
-- Name: plpgsql; Type: EXTENSION; Schema: -; Owner: -
--

CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS plpgsql WITH SCHEMA pg_catalog;


--
-- Name: EXTENSION plpgsql; Type: COMMENT; Schema: -; Owner: -
--

COMMENT ON EXTENSION plpgsql IS 'PL/pgSQL procedural language';


SET search_path = public, pg_catalog;

SET default_tablespace = '';

SET default_with_oids = false;

--
-- Name: listings; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: -
--

CREATE TABLE listings (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    item_name character varying,
    description character varying,
    price integer,
    shipping_cost integer,
    created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    category_id bigint,
    sub_category_id bigint,
    size_id bigint,
    user_id bigint,
    full_item_name text,
    cached_votes_total integer DEFAULT 0,
    cached_votes_score integer DEFAULT 0,
    cached_votes_up integer DEFAULT 0,
    cached_votes_down integer DEFAULT 0,
    cached_weighted_score integer DEFAULT 0,
    cached_weighted_total integer DEFAULT 0,
    cached_weighted_average double precision DEFAULT 0.0,
    flaremeter integer DEFAULT 0,
    condition_id bigint,
    cover_photo_data text
);


--
-- Name: listings_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE; Schema: public; Owner: -
--

CREATE SEQUENCE listings_id_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;


--
-- Name: listings_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE OWNED BY; Schema: public; Owner: -
--

ALTER SEQUENCE listings_id_seq OWNED BY listings.id;


--
-- PostgreSQL database dump complete
--

SET search_path TO "$user", public;

INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES
('20200223103428'),
('20200313111818'),
('20200313140854'),
('20200321060306');
```

Comment: I would start by splitting this into two migrations so that you can tackle one problem at a time.

Comment: I've already tried splitting the migration up (One for adding the column + index and another for creating the trigger) and it still wouldn't work. I've also tried including the column + index in a previous migration where the Listings table is created and that didn't work either.

Comment: Does this just happen for tsvector columns? For the purpose of debugging try creating a migration that just adds a varchar column. As a last resort you can always just write `add_column` and `add_index` as SQL instead.

Comment: Turns out that I had the def up and def down defined inside def change. Removing the def change method solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the def up and def down defined inside def change. Removing the def change method solved my issue.